# Working with Enum?

Tags: java, enums

Have a bit of trouble working with enums, how do you pass a method to an enum?  This is a basic overview of the code:

```
public enum myEnum{
            UNDEFINED, Value1, Value2
}

checkEnum(myEnum passedValue){
//do check stuff here
}
```

No I want to pass "Value1" to checkEnum but if I just say:

```
checkEnum(Value1);
```

Eclipse won't let me, in what format does my variable have to be to pass it to my method checkEnum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
checkEnum(myEnum.Value1);
```

Also, the convention is to start Enums and Class names in upper case letter. e.g.

```
checkEnum(MyEnum.Value1);
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I'm making the call from another class?

Comment: The same. if you are doing it from a separate package though, you will need to import the Enum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
checkEnum(myEnum.Value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be qualified, `checkEnum(myEnum.Value1);` should work.